# Custom control with and without autolayout

Tags: objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I will be creating a custom control (based on UIView).

Is there a way it could work with UIViewControllers using auto layout as well as UIViewControllers that do not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control should work in both cases. The difference is that in one case you will use constraints to layout it and in the other one, setting the frame programmatically.

If your control contains other subviews, it is important how you configure these. For example, if you do the setup of the subviews in `initWithFrame:` and you use the given frame to layout them (meaning static frames, instead of constraints), in the auto layout `viewControllers`, the frames will no get updated.

However, layouting the subviews with constraints will have no impact on the non-autolayout `viewControllers`. The subviews will have the layout according to your constraints, in the given static frame of the custom control.

It is a general explanation since I don't know that much about your particular controller. Hope this makes sense and you can find helpful.